# Brief Startup Voltage in DC RL Circuit

Tags: led, dc, inductor, passive-networks

I'm a recently-graduated electrical engineering student and I've been testing storage capacity of inductors and capacitors in simple DC circuits for circuit control. I wound up making the circuit below.

[image]

My confusion with the circuit is the behavior of D1. If the switch has been closed for a few seconds and I open it quickly, D1 lights up very briefly (milliseconds) which is as I expect. The inductance is small so the energy dissipates quickly.

However if the switch is open and I close it very quickly D1 ALSO lights for a few milliseconds. Based on my understanding I can't work out how there could be a voltage across D1 at any point when the switch transitions from inactive to active.

Can anyone please shed some light or why this might be happening? Is it simply due to the non-ideal nature of real components or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ANY change in the current through an inductor causes a voltage to appear across it.

Comment: Ever heard of switch bounce?

Comment: Brian's nailed it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond How about putting that up as an answer so we can put this one to bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the most likely cause is the non-ideal behaviour of ...

the switch.

Mechanical switches don't deliver a clean On/Off behaviour, they make and break contact for (typically) a few milliseconds  before they settle to a final state. Age, wear, and dirt/oxidation on the contacts make the problem worse.

This is called [switch bounce](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/287) and you'll find many articles describing it.

It's usually encountered when controlling digital circuits with a push button ("why did pushing the button once count to 17?") and there are whole families of switch de-bouncing circuits and software routines, as in the linked article from Maxim.

But it can also be used to generate interesting unexpected voltages with inductive circuits, as you found.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I have heard of switch bounce so that would make sense. My method of switching however has actually been connecting and disconnecting the positive supply lead from the battery to the positive rail of my breadboard rather than using a mechanical switch (I said switch just to try and make my question a little clearer). Even though it's not mechanical would "switch bounce" still occur in this case?

Comment: I should also mention, I tried the circuit with a mechanical switch but didn't see any LED spiking (on or off) so I assume the switches I have aren't fast enough

Comment: @andystringfield That's a mechanical switch. If you have an oscilloscope, you could test this by connecting one end of a resistor to your negative supply (and scope ground), and the other end to a scope probe, and then plugging the probed end into your positive supply.

Comment: @immibis So put a load across supply to be able to observe the switch bounce signal/s?

Comment: @andystringfield Yes. (after the switch, and noting that plugging in a wire *is* a low-quality mechanical switch).